# Is there a package or common set of shortcuts for Neovim/Vim in "insert" or "i" mode?

Tags: neovim

Coming from bunch of years of using the VS Code environment in Windows I'm used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + some keys to manage the interface. In Vim/Neovim I always have to exit insert mode to do most operations.

Are there any preset Insert Mode shortcuts that the longtime Vim users are already using or do I have to get used to the Vim way.

Comment: "do I have to get used to the Vim way." - no, you can install VS Code on Linux and you'll be fine. Pick the right tool for the right job. If VS Code suits you, just use it. Actually, there's a ton of editors installed on any Linux system. One of them is bound to have MS-like key bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advise is to get used to the Vim way which is to use the insert mode to input text and leave insert mode to do the other actions (move, delete, ...).

## Ctrl-o

That being said the <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd>`...` let you do one normal mode action while staying the insert mode.

e.g.: <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd>`$` move the cursor to the end of the line.

## Leaving Insert Mode

I also had that temptation when starting Vim since the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key was quite faraway until I discovered that the <kbd>Ctrl [</kbd> key is a synonym for <kbd>Esc</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl ^</kbd> on a Beligian keyboard).

Some are changing their keyboard configuration to map <kbd>Cap Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> their are several tool to allow that. I'm using: [uncap](https://github.com/susam/uncap)

Comment: Sometimes the obvious questions are the hardest to ask in a professional environment. Appreciate the help. I use the ```Caps Lock``` has been converted to ```Void``` using Kmonad.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Thanks for the feedback! If the answer adress your question maybe you could accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow, the question to rest :-)